# Return a for loop printed grid from a function/method

Tags: java, function, return

How would one go about returning the grid that is printed in the below function/method? I am using a String function/method but I am not sure at all of how I would return what is printed out in this function/method in my main class.

```
public static String Grid(){
    int[][] map = new int[4][4]; 
    map[x][y] = entry;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            if (counter != 2) {
                if (j < 2) {
                    System.out.print("+---");
                } else if (j == 2) {
                    System.out.print("++---+");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("---+");
                }
            }
            else{
                if (j < 2) {
                    System.out.print("+===");
                } else if (j == 2) {
                    System.out.print("++===+");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("===+");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            if (j < 2) {
                System.out.print("| " + map[i][j] + " ");
            } else if (j == 2) {
                System.out.print("|| " + map[i][j]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(" | " + map[i][j] + " |");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.print("+---+---++---+---+");
    System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Store it in a string array and return that?

Comment: Create a StringBuilder object and append everything you are currently printing to it. Then return that StringBuilder's `toString()`.

Comment: I don't know the context, but *returning* the String doesn't seem what one usually wants. In other words, I kind of smell an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'd rather create a `Grid` class and then overwrite the `toString()` method with the code you have here. Maybe provide us with a bit more context so we can give better advice.

Comment: The provided code doesn't compile, and there are too many possible answers, please clarify what are your requirements

Answer (score 2):

Create a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
```

Replace every

```
System.out.println();
```

with

```
result.append("\n");
```

and replace

```
System.out.print(string);
```

with

```
result.append(string);
```

At the end of the method, add

```
return result.toString();
```